# Derivative Counterexamples - Calculus

Tags: calculus

I need counterexamples for the following (I guess these claims are not correct):

1. If $ lim_{n\to \infty} n\cdot (f(\frac{1}{n}) - f(0) ) =0$ then $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and $f'(0)=0$ .
2. If f is defined in a neighberhood of $a$ including $a$ and differentiable at a neighberhood of $a$ (except maybe at $a$ itself), and $lim_{x\to a^- } f'(x) = lim_{x\to a^+} f'(x) $ , then $f$ is differentiable at $x=a$.
3. If $f$ is diff for all $x$ and satisfies $lim_{x\to \infty } f'(x) =0 $ then there exists a number $L<\infty$ for which $ lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)= L$
4. If $f$ is diff for all $x$ and satisfies $lim _{x\to \infty} f(x)= L $ then $lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)=0 $ .
5. If $f $ is diff at $x=0$ and $lim_{x\to 0 } \frac{f(x)}{x} =3 $ , then $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=3$

Thoughts:

5) I think this claim is correct and follows from the uniqueness of the derivative... I have no idea how to prove it, but it sounds reasonable

3) Isn't a counterexample for this is $f(x)=lnx$ ?

4) I have tried using some trigonometric functions, but still couldn't manage to find a counterexample

2) I guess that an example for this would be a function that its derivative isn't defined at this point , but its limits do

1) have no idea... It sounds incorrect (although I guess that the other direction of the claim is correct)

Help?

Thanks !

Comment: For 5., use the definition of derivative: $f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x$, so if $f(0)=0$, we are done. But $f(0)=\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0}x\cdot\frac{f(x)}x=0\cdot3=0$. Here, I used that $f(0)=\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$, which means that $f$ is continuous at $0$, which we know is true since $f$ is differentiable at $0$, and differentiability entails continuity.

Comment: For 4 consider something like $f(x)=\frac{\sin(e^x)}{x^2+1}$.

Comment: @Eric : Can you please explain why does that limit of your example doesn't go do zero ? The derivative of what you mentioned goes to infinity ? Thanks!

Comment: @AndresCaicedo : Thanks a lot!

Comment: For the function, $f(x)$, that I gave above, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$.  If you don't want it to be zero just add $L$ to it.  The derivative is $\frac{e^x\cos(e^x)(x^2+1)-\sin(e^x)2x}{(x^2+1)^2}$ so the limit of $f'(x)$ does not exist.  It might be easier to consider something like $\frac{\sin(x^3)}{x^2+1}$.  We use this denominator because it is non-zero for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

1. There is a lot of space between $1/n$
2. The only place to go wrong is at $x=a$.  Break it there.

Comment: 1) I know. this is why I guess the claim is incorrect. But I can't find any proper counterexample that will allow the limit to be zero if I plug in $\frac{1}{n}$ , but won't be zero for other values...
2) I tried using $f(x)=x^2, x\neq 0 $ and $f(0)=4$ , but it doesn't work, because the derivative will be 0 in any case... will you please help me with these 2? THanks !

Answer (score 1):

$5$. Think, if you take the limit you get $\frac{0}{0}$, what can you use then?

$4$. What would it mean if the derivative were positive or negative 'all the way' to infinity?

$3$. Your example works just fine since $\log x$ is differentiable for all $x$ in its domain, it's slopes go to $0$, and the function grows without bound.

$2$. If a function is differentiable, then it is continuous. Think of the parabola $f(x)=x^2$ at the origin, think about the slopes as you approach $0$ from the left/right. Is there something you could do to the parabola at $0$ to make the statement untrue?

$1$. Think derivative definition.

Comment: If I get you right, according to your first argument $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{3x}{3}=\frac{0}{0}\neq 3$.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to motivate with your hint for number four.  Can you expand on that a bit?

Comment: @flonk You don't follow. Think l'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: @Eric If the derivative is nonzero, the function is either...or.... . So the function does what? Moreover, if the derivative 'cycles' causing the function to oscillate, can the function even approach a limit, this means....

Comment: A function with an oscillating derivative can approach a limit.  Consider the example I gave in a comment to the original question.

Comment: @Eric I wasn't trying to say that. The case where the derivative oscillates clearly prevents $\lim f'(x)=0$, unless the derivative both oscillates and decreases. That would need to be a separate consideration.

Comment: @mathematics2x2life : I think I managed with everything, except for 1 and 2 .
1) I guess it is incorrect ... but can't find any counterexample.

2) I want to put the value of $f'(0)$ different from the one of $f'(x)$ obviously... But defining the function differently at $0$ doesn't work (see my comment above)
Will you help ? Thanks !

Comment: @criticism For $2$, that is not the idea. Take the ordinary parabola except at $x=0$ have the value of the function by $1$. So the new parabola meets all the requirements except being discontinuous at $x=0$, it cannot be differentiable there. For $1$, write down the derivative definition for $x=0$. Then instead of letting $\Delta x$ go to $0$, can you find another function which goes to $0$ in some limit? How about $1/n$ as $n$ goes to infinity? So could you replace $\Delta x$ with $1/n$ and let $n$ go to infinity. Try that replacement then use some algebra. Does it look like $1$?

Comment: @mathematics2x2life : Thanks for 2. As for 1- I am not sure I understand... You only take a specific way to tend to zero ($\frac{1}{n} $ ) ... No one tells you that by taking other ways to tend to zero, you'll get the same result

Comment: @criticism See Eric's answer, which was what I was trying to help you see.

Answer (score 1):

For 1, if $\lim_{n\to\infty}n(f(1/n)-f(0))=0$ then we have $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(\frac{1}{n})-f(0)}{\frac{1}{n}}=0$.  It is common to assume that $n$ denotes a natural number but this was not indicated in the problem statement.  So assuming the stronger statement (i.e. that the limit is taken for $n\in\mathbb{R}$) this is equivalent to $$\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=0.$$  This does not mean that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$ exists.  For a counterexample think up a piecewise function.  Something like the following:
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0& :x\geq0\\h(x)&:x<0
\end{array}\right..$$
Notice that this will satisfy the conditions of 1 regardless of what $h(x)$ is.